# Bonuses awarded on Mathstackexchange

Tags: support, reputation, stackexchange

A month or two ago i was awarded the association bonus (still wondering what is it). I wanted to know are there any other bonuses awarded by M.SE, if there are how can i earn them.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why has this got a downvote? It isn't contentious, and isn't that easy to search for...(searching for something which isn't there isn't generally easy!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no other reputation bonuses (unless you count reputation earned through upvotes, bounties, suggesting edits, and acceptance of answers).  You can read about the association bonus [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/).

Comment: Will this bonus stack up? (i.e. 200 rep on 2 sites will means 2*100 association bonus for accounts on other SE sites)

Comment: @freak_warrior: No, just 100 on each site, no matter on how many sites you have acquired 200 points.